# Selenium+Python3 - Unable to find the ID for these Print and Download icons

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Selenium newbie here ... I cannot find a way to interact with these icons (Print and Export) from my Python + Selenium program  ... any guidance someone can offer?

The icons on the web browser here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Rw4.png

When you "Inspect" any of these icons with Chrome browser, you see this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zaacv.png

Both icons appear without an ID or a Name.  How could I 'select' to 'click' on one of these icons, and how to differentiate between these two?

Tks!

------- Found the way to do it with CSS Selector:

webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.POgU2 button:nth-of-type(2)')

Tks all.

Answer (score 0):

The icons are not images, they are generated from a tff file using CSS so you cannot use selenium or requests to get them.

Comment: Selenium can select any element in the Document Object Model. Sometimes it's tricky to address it, but whether there is an image or not is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can select them using XPATH or CSS Selectors.  Even though the two  tags stupidly have exactly the same class and child span & class, it's still possibly to differentiate between them because of their relative positions within the DOM.

For one example, we could select the SECOND instance with an approach like this:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='POgU2']/button/following-sibling::button/").click()
```

There are many other ways to arrive at it.

Comment: Thank you.  This is giving me an error:   SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//<div[@class='POgU2']/button/following-sibling::button/' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)

Comment: IDon't know why, but I wasn't able to make xpath to work.   Finally i was able to accomplish the task with:

webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.POgU2 button:nth-of-type(2)')

Thanks!

Comment: Well, my original reply was logically correct but stupidly had a "<" character in it next to the div.  Remove that.  Also, in your first reply above, you've used single quotes inside a single-quoted string.  Look at my example, which was delimited by double-quotes for that reason.